# Google Adwords Tracking Code causing too many redirects error

Tags: google

Google Adwords Tracking Code causing too many redirects error - when adding in the code in the header of the site just get a too many redirects error
Have tried everything from .htaccess, wp-config file, removed all plugins to check they did anything any other suggestions?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the CODE you are using for this.

Answer (score 0):

In general, isn't it better to put the Tracking code in the footer area (so that the content gets loaded before the tracking code)?

But, without looking at your code, make sure that you copy/pasted the code from Adwords and didn't inadvertently miss some code.

If you comment out your tracking code (or otherwise disable it), will the page load correctly (without redirect errors)? If so, then the code is 'damaged' in some way.